# Laravel 5.2 withTrashed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel and I wanted to look at the `withTrashed()` method but I couldn't find it anywhere. I looked through the files in my IDE and there was no sign of it. Then I went through the API Docs of Laravel and I couldn't find it there either. But when I use it in my code it works. Where is it located then? And what does it return(I only c+p from the code snippets in the docs)?

Comment: After doing some digging it appears to be located in the SoftDeletingScope.php, which returns the builder instance withoutGlobalScope() applied to it. So it just allows the query to run without the soft delete global scope applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, the code looks to be contained in

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletingScope.php
```

Specifically:

```
// 12: 
protected $extensions = ['Restore', 'WithTrashed', 'WithoutTrashed', 'OnlyTrashed'];

// 71:
$builder->macro('restore', function (Builder $builder) {
  $builder->withTrashed();
  ...

// 83 and 85:
protected function addWithTrashed(Builder $builder){
  $builder->macro('withTrashed', function (Builder $builder) {
    return $builder->withoutGlobalScope($this);
});
```